# Device Token requirement in push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, unity-game-engine

I actually implemented push notification service into my game but I have some questions in my mind those I want to clear.

Implementation totally done on our custom server so not used any third party service help in this. I have used core Unity push notification code for this purpose.

[NotificationServices.deviceToken](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.NotificationServices.RegisterForNotifications.html)

After registration was complete, I need to add deviceToken to web server. Why I need to do this? I can't able to get this concept.

If I add SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier then it will not able to send any push notification. It can only able to work with deviceToken.

Please share your suggestions with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushnotification is work only on device token,you have to get it and store it on server.

We stored device token on server, sothat server send notification to the all user.
If we don't save device token then, server how to send notification and where (Device token is the unique id for every device).

In app delegate you have to get it with this method

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app
                   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
 {

       const unsigned *tokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
       NSString *hexToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                      ntohl(tokenBytes[0]), ntohl(tokenBytes[1]), ntohl(tokenBytes[2]),
                      ntohl(tokenBytes[3]), ntohl(tokenBytes[4]), ntohl(tokenBytes[5]),
                      ntohl(tokenBytes[6]), ntohl(tokenBytes[7])];

     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:hexToken forKey:@"DeviceTokenValue"];// Save your device token for use
     [self saveDeviceToken:hexToken];//Send your device token to the server with API

  }
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Is deviceToke value remain unique always?

Comment: after iOS 9, it will change every time, if user uninstall the app and then install the app. otherwise it will same ....And device token is always different for every device.
You have to call the register device method only once 
In didFinishLaunchingOptions method you have to check, that device token is saved in NSUserDefaults or not, If not saved then call the register method

Comment: Okay I got what you are trying to say. So may I just need to get deviceToken and registration process only single time in full app life? when user run it first time.

Comment: you need to register your APNS

Comment: @Siddharth Yes you have to call it only one time, if you got your device token then save it in nsuserdefaultes and check it everytime if it is exist then no need to call it again.

Comment: @ParvendraSingh, Really thank you sir :) Just give me last doubt reply. Now at sending time via admin panel, I am getting this kind of bug. Before it is working correctly but now it is showing this error, can you give me some hint in this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/mw6homf8llnzo9l/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-26%20at%2012.43.48%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: @Siddharth  Are you created the APNS Certificate on Developer.apple.com
If you created it then you have to export it in .p12 file and then a pem file, you have to save this pem file on server...... If you are not created pem file then create it

Comment: @Siddharth Please follow the process for notification services 
take help from here 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: @ParvendraSingh, I have already created this pem file and given this to web developer and for 2 days, I have notification in my device as well but right now I am getting this error. is it web developer's mistake?

Comment: @ParvendraSingh, by seeing error, what is your opinion? at which place mistake exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110718/discussion-between-siddharth-and-parvendra-singh).